# How to reauthenticate Users with Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Using a Parse Server for my application, I want my users to reauthenticate for certain actions (e.g. changing the email address).

I thought about simply asking the user to sign in again before changing the email, but this would be just a reauthentication on the client side.

I am looking for a solution that requires reauthentication on the server side to change certain data like the user email.

Does anyone knows a way to accomplish this with Parse Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Code and try log in with username and password:

```
const user = await Parse.User.logIn("username", "password");
```

If the user logs in successfully and you retrieve the `Parse.User` object, you know that the credentials provided are correct. This creates a new user session but it won't invalidate the existing session of the user.

There is currently no way of logging out the user to easily destroy the session you just created, because `Parse.User.current()` is always `null` in Cloud Code. But the session will simply expire if you don't use it anymore, or you can delete the session manually from the `Session` class.

In addition you may want to verify that `request.user` is the same one as the validated user, so you know the user entered the credentials for the user account they are currently logged in with.

Parse Server currently has no specific feature for what you mention here, but it has a supportive community, so you may want to [open a PR](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues) to add this feature to Parse Server.